# Access data outside for loop

Tags: java, jar

I have a main class and a UI class.

Let me do some explaining first. What i am doing currently, is processing some jar files to find all of the classname inside them (to use later with reflection)

In main, i do things and process data and in the UI there is a JTabbedPane that loads a JFrame when a plugin is correctly loaded (To do so, I share the UI class from main and then invoke it).

Now, to make this dynamic, i made a nice for loop that loops through all jars and gets all the classnames.

Question is, **how do i access those strings found in the for loop externally?**

***EDIT***
A commenter pointed out that I could just declare the strings outside the for loop, problem is **I have no clue on how many jars i will load** and for the sake of user convenience, *I'd like to keep the main program as it is* (so **no updates**, **just plugin updates** that can be handled inside the jar itself at runtime)

Sorry if this is dumb.

Comment: declare the string outside the for loop and assign the value inside the for loop

Comment: Problem is that I don't know how many jars i will load, so I thought that assigning 20 empty strings is a bad idea. Isn't there a way to make this more efficient?

Comment: Look up the `List` class in java and how to use it. Then just add it all to a `List<String>`. Also, not to be insulting but: Do you really think its a good idea to do something with reflection when you don't even have good knowledge of basic datatypes of java?

Comment: You can use a List<Jars>  out side the loop.

Comment: @downvoter, why the downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As people in the comments said your best choice would be to declare a list of `String` outside the loop:

```
List<String> classnames = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String classname : jar) {
    classnames.add(classname);
}
```

Something like this.

Comment: Great way to get pretty much free rep. Nonetheless thank you and everyone who commented.

Comment: Sorry if that felt like an attempt to get free reputation. Feel free to tick off the best answer choice.